# Find Duplicate in column b for each value in column A Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have Table like Below:

```
Sr_No   C_A  C_B
-------------------
1       100  A
2       100  A
3       100  B
4       101  A
5       102  A
6       102  B
7       103  A
8       103  A
9       103  B
```

And I want select query to get below

```
C_A 
----
100 
103
```

I want to know how many records are in C_A column having duplicate values in C_B column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query below checks, for each `C_A` group, that the number of distinct `C_B` values is less than the total number of values.  This condition implies that all `C_B` values are not unique for a given `C_A` group, and that there are duplicates.

```
SELECT C_A
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY C_A
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C_B) < COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you may need:

```
select distinct C_A
from 
    (select C_A, C_B, count(1) over ( partition by C_A, C_B) as cnt
     from test
    )
where cnt > 1
```

The nested query counts the number of duplicates for each couple of values in `C_A`, `C_B`, while the external one simply filters this result to only get couples with duplicates